# How to read and write Session in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: session, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cake 3.0. I have read documentation on 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html
But I am not able to write sessions.

```
use Cake\Network\Session\DatabaseSession;

$session->write('Config.language', 'eng'); 
$session->read('Config.language');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update : For CakePHP 3.6+, see @shubham715 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270164)**

The following applies to CakePHP before 3.6 :

You need to set $session :

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->write('Config.language', 'eng'); 
$session->read('Config.language');
```

And then you'll be able to read and write in your session

Or you can direclty read and write :

```
$this->request->session()->write('Config.language', 'eng');
$this->request->session()->read('Config.language');
```

Comment: Also if we want to destroy session, then we need to write $session->destroy(); ?

Comment: Unfortunately same thing as the documentation. Your answer does not say how to read session in a Controller.

Comment: Heads up: needs to be `$this->getRequest()` for recent versions, see @shubham715's answer

Answer (score 5):

**Version 3.6.0 and above use `getRequest()` and `getSession()` [Document](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object).**

```
$name = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('User.name');
```

And if you are accessing the session multiple times, you will probably want a local variable.

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$name = $session->read('User.name');
```

Comment: It's the other way around. In the doc it says "// Prior to 3.6.0 use session() instead.". You can see the doc [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object)

Answer (score 3):

I use this its works fine

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->write('annul_income','$100,00,00');//Write
echo $session->read('annul_income')//To read the session value   o/p:$100,00,00
```