# How to pass data from one controller to another in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanna pass a variable from userscontroller to salescontroller in my project in CakePHP 3 and use it in salescontroller .But I don`t wanna to redirect from an action to another one (not passing variables in url) how can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like there is flaw in your application design. Controllers should not communicate with each other. If there is shared functionality, put it in a component (the service layer) or in the model layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :** to pass data between controller, you can use **Session**,

```
$session = $this->request->session();
```

how to read and write read link bnelow

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568653/how-to-read-and-write-session-in-cakephp-3-0

Comment: There is no session component in CakePHP 3.x anymore.